# HTML 5 drag & drop with Angular Typescript

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I am testing the HTML5 drag and drop with the Angular application. Just wondering what is wrong here. I have the below code in the app.component.html file.

```
<div>
  <p draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">Coffee</p>
</div>
```

And I have this in the Typescript file app.component.ts

```
export class AppComponent {

 function drag(ev) {
    console.log(ev);
  }
}
```

It says reference error in the console of the browser. Why is it not outputting anything on the console? Please advise!

Comment: Use angular way of events replace ondragstart with (dragstart)

Comment: Where do I find the Angular events? Any links?

Comment: It has all the supported events by html just remove on from event and surround with () example for onclick it is (click) ,onsubmit is (submit)

Comment: Any custom event or dom event is captured with a (eventwithouton) . Check angular getting started in the angular.io site

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In angular2/4/5/6/7/8 replace **(onevents) with (events)**
see the example below

ondrop        with            (drop)

ondragover    with          (dragover)

ondragstart   with          (dragstart)

Comment: Took me a day to figure out what's wrong and you saved me, thank you!